# Are closed questions impacting the statistics at area 51?

Tags: discussion, statistics

In [Islam at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam), it says we have 83% questions answered while we should work to get more: "90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some work. In the beta it's especially important that when new visitors ask questions they usually get a good answer."

**Are questions that get closed included in this statistics?** *If that is the case wouldn't more closed questions result in less % answered questions?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Questions per day

According to [this meta.SE thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294533/351283), this is the median daily number of questions in the last two weeks.  Comparing the numbers for [`created:14d.. is:question`](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A14d..%20is%3Aquestion) with [`created:14d.. is:question closed:false`](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A14d..%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3Afalse), it looks like it includes closed questions.

### Answered ratio

This is answered at meta.SE by [Emmett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86976/351283) (copy/pasted below).  If this is accurate, closed questions are counted the same as answered questions.  So closed questions with no upvoted answers will increase the ratio.

### Avid/total users

Does not affect the calculation (but closing people's questions may affect whether or not they become avid users).

### Answer ratio

According to [Emmett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86976/351283)'s answer, closed questions with no answers will increase both `total_questions` and `answeredPercentage`, lowering the answer ratio.

(I'd guess this is affected somewhat by goldPseudo's tendency to diamond-hammer delete worthless answers.)

### Visits per day

Does not affect the calculation (but closing questions would affect the visits per day).

---

[Emmett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86976/351283)'s answer:

> We use numbers returned by the public /stats api, e.g.
>   http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.1/stats:
>
> ```
> answeredPercentage = 100 - (total_unanswered / total_questions * 100);
> answerRatio = total_answers / (total_questions * answeredPercentage / 100);
> ```
>
> But slightly confusingly, the api's return values for
>   `total_questions` and `total_answers` include closed questions, but
>   `total_unanswered` doesn't.
>
> So, `answeredPercentage` ("% answered" on the stats page) is actually
>   "percentage of questions that have been resolved" ...either by an
>   answer or by closing.

Answer (score 2):

Closed questions will not count towards the Unanswered metric.